# How to call a function from another script?

Tags: c#

I've read a bunch of guides on how to do this, but being new to programming I'm not really getting it.

I have a script called DatabaseHandler where I wrote a new class and function to write some basic user information to a Firebase database when someone creates a new account.

```
DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
public class User
{
    public string email;
    public int score;
    public int round;
    public int lives;

    public User()
    {
    }

    public User(string email)
    {
        this.email = email;
        this.score = 0;
        this.round = 1;
        this.lives = 3;
    }
}

public void writeNewUser(string email, int score, int round, int lives)
{
    User user = new User(email);
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(user);

    userRef.Child("users").Child(email).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
}
```

Also, I have another script called LoginHandler that calls CreateUserAsync() when someone click the button to create an account. I'm using a code snippet I found on a guide online for this part, and am trying to figure out where and how I can call the writeNewUser function that's written in DatabaseHandler from within LoginHandler? Should I call it from Task HandleCreateUserAsync after the auth.CurrentUser != null to make sure the data is only written if the username has not already been created?

```
public void CreateUserAsync() {
DebugLog(String.Format("Attempting to create user {0}...", email));

// This passes the current displayName through to HandleCreateUserAsync
// so that it can be passed to UpdateUserProfile().  displayName will be
// reset by AuthStateChanged() when the new user is created and signed in.
string newDisplayName = displayName;
auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password)
  .ContinueWith((task) => {
    return HandleCreateUserAsync(task, newDisplayName: newDisplayName);
  }).Unwrap();
 }

 Task HandleCreateUserAsync(Task<Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser> authTask,
                         string newDisplayName = null) {
 if (LogTaskCompletion(authTask, "User Creation")) {
  if (auth.CurrentUser != null) {
    DebugLog(String.Format("User Info: {0}  {1}", auth.CurrentUser.Email,
                           auth.CurrentUser.ProviderId));
    return UpdateUserProfileAsync(newDisplayName: newDisplayName);
  }
}
// Nothing to update, so just return a completed Task.
return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what are you asking. You have two c# "scripts"? If so then I have to disappoint you (while it is possible) but usually c# files are compiled in to libraries from where they are called

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned I'm using Unity, and have two scripts in my assets folder. One script handles creating login credentials, but I need to call another script which handles manipulating the database. When someone creates an account, I need to call a function to also update my database with information about the user when they create a new account.

Comment: Firebase stores the users e-mail when creating a new account, but I also want the database to store the user's score and other basic information so that the game will save their progress to a remote database instead of locally.

Comment: There is many ways to get reference to another script. You can use get components or make events (if I remember correctly unity has own messaging system for that already) or (never tryed in unity) use dependensy injections, etc. Big question is also if all your "scripts" classes are driven from unity itself (that limits you usually).I believe most common way to solve it is by making game control script with all the required references.